# Собрать объект, пройдя по элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть группа элементов, выглядят они так:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_aaa">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_bbb">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_ccc">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_ddd">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_aaa">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_bbb">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ccc">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ddd">
</div>
```

Как из этого собрать объект, такого типа:

```
{
    "nameOne": {
        "aaa": "",
        "bbb": "",
        "ccc": "",
        "ddd": ""
    },
    "nameTwo": {
        "aaa": "",
        "bbb": "",
        "ccc": "",
        "ddd": ""
    }
}
```

Где `arr[n]` - ключ равен значению из атрибута `name` (части **до** `_`), значение (`arr[n][n]`), равно другому объекту,
где `arr[n][n]` - ключ равен атрибуту `[name]` (части **после** `_`), а значение равно `value` этого `input`'а или `textarea`

Comment: а в чем сложность?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не умею :с | "Групп" может быть разное кол-во, по-этому мне нужно это всё собирать кодом, а потом отправлять как json.

Comment: это все ограничения?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, кажется да.. Пытался найти сам что-то похожее на мою задачу, но видать я слеп.. | Сейчас пытаюсь костылями хоть что-то сделать..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

let json = {}

for( let i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
  let name = input[i].name.match(/^(.+?)_(.+)$/); // (*1)
  let key = name[1];
  let val = name[2];

  if( !json[key] ){ // Если объекта с найденным именем еще нет - создаем.
    json[key] = {}
  }

  json[key][val] = "";
}

console.log( json );
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="nameOne_aaa">
  <input type="text" name="nameOne_bbb">
  <input type="text" name="nameOne_ccc">
  <input type="text" name="nameOne_ddd">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="nameTwo_aaa">
  <input type="text" name="nameTwo_bbb">
  <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ccc">
  <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ddd">
</div>
```

(*1): `.name.match(/^(.+?)_(.+)$/)` — `^` начало строки, `$` - конец сроки. `.` точка совпадает с любым символом, а `+` плюсик означает "один или много раз". При этом, match возвращает массив из найденных совпадений. 

Скажем, их строки nameTwo_aaa вернет `["nameTwo_aaa", "nameTwo", "aaa"]` — оттуда и можно достать 2-й и 3-й элементы по индексам [1] и [2]

P.s. да, разумнее было использовать split, как в соседнем ответе!)

Answer (score 3):

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const obj = {};

inputs.forEach( input => {
  
  const names = input.getAttribute("name").split('_');
 
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(names[0])) {
    obj[names[0]] = {};
  }
  
  obj[names[0]][names[1]] = '';
  
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<div class="select">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_aaa">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_bbb">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_ccc">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_ddd">
</div>

<div class="select">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_aaa">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_bbb">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ccc">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ddd">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так, например:

```js
let result = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
  .map(el => el.name)
  .reduce((a, e) => {
    let b = e.split('_'), c = b[0];
    return (a[c] || (a[c] = {}))[b[1]] = "", a;
  }, {});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_aaa">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_bbb">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_ccc">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne_ddd">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_aaa">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_bbb">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ccc">
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo_ddd">
</div>
```

Comment: Ааа, сложный выбор. Оба варианта рабочих, оба идеальных..

Comment: @Отдай оптимусу, он первый ответил

Comment: Пожалуй так и сделаю, надеюсь без обид)